# Mark.groups in Igraph Error: unknown vertex.names selected

Tags: r, igraph

I am trying to create a network plot in igraph where

1. communities are marked by a color overlay as created by mark.groups
2. nodes are colored by a node attribute: deu
3. nodes are shaped a node attribute: topic_type

For this, I created an igraph object

And now, I try the following code:

```
set.seed(2)
plot(graph_deu,
     mark.groups=list(c(33,1,34,2,36,53,54,56,42,43,55,57,18), c(35,48,50,27), c(38,45,46,47,49,28,25)),
     mark.col=c("lemonchiffon", "slategray1", "thistle1"), 
     mark.border = NA, 
     edge.width =E(graph_deu)$weight,
     vertex.size = deu_deg,
     vertex.color = deu,
     vertex.shape = topic_type,
     vertex.label = node_labels,
     vertex.label.cex=1.5
     )
```

And I get the error:

> Fehler in simple_vs_index(x, ii, na_ok) : Unknown vertex selected.

This seems to be igraph not finding the vertices as specified in mark.groups, but I have actually no idea why it would not find these vertices, as they are all correctly numbered.

Then, to avoid mark.groups, I tried another option - I directly plot the community object (mod2), however, in this case, nodes get colored according to community and not according to attribute `deu`:

```
plot(mod2, graph_deu,
     edge.width =E(graph_deu)$weight,
     vertex.size = deu_deg,
     vertex.color = deu,
     vertex.shape = topic_type,
     vertex.label = node_labels,
     vertex.label.cex=1.5)
```

This produces a  network where vertices are colored by community, not by deu-attribute. What I would like it to look: I would like the communities to be circled by the semi-transparent overlay, but the nodes should be individually colored by deu-attribute.

Your help will be very appreciated. this is my first post on stackoverflow so if I should provide more pieces of code to reproduce I am happy to share it, I hope though that my igraph object is enough for the problem at hand.

Comment: Please use `dput(graph_deu)` and paste the result into your question so that we can work with the grapph exactly as you have it.

Comment: @G5W I just edited my question and added the informatoin. Thanks!

Comment: The graph that you provide only has 24 nodes. So when you write `mark.groups=list(c(33,1,34,2,36,53,54,56,42,43,55,57,18) ...` you are referring to nodes that don't exist.  There are no nodes numbered 33,34,53,54, etc.

Comment: @G5W why not? It shows so in the graph object - these are the vertices names. How else should I refer to my vertices, if not with their names? thank you for your help!

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1):

Your graph has only 24 nodes, but you are referring to nodes using number higher than that, e.g. 36,53,54.  If you use a number,  igraph assumes that is the *number* of the node,   so these number don't make sense for this graph. What you mean is the nodes with the *names*  "36","53","54".  The names are strings,  not numbers. What you need to do is find the node numbers that correspond to these names. I show one way to do that below.  Also,  your plot statement refers to a number of variables that you did not provide so I commented them out here.

```
graph_deu = upgrade_graph(graph_deu)
plot(graph_deu)


Group1 = as.numeric(V(graph_deu)[as.character(c(33,1,34,2,36,53,54,56,42,43,55,57,18))])
Group2 = as.numeric(V(graph_deu)[as.character(c(35,48,50,27))])
Group3 = as.numeric(V(graph_deu)[as.character(c(38,45,46,47,49,28,25))])

set.seed(2)
plot(graph_deu,
     mark.groups=list(Group1, Group2, Group3),
     mark.col=c("lemonchiffon", "slategray1", "thistle1"), 
     mark.border = NA, 
     edge.width =E(graph_deu)$weight,
     # vertex.size = deu_deg,
     # vertex.color = deu,
     # vertex.shape = topic_type,
     # vertex.label = node_labels,
     vertex.label.cex=1.5
     )
```